# How do I breed a Fog dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I want to breed a Peridot dragon, and crystal and cactus doesn't work for me after about twenty tries, give or take a few. So I'm going to go for the fog and iron combination. Anyone know how to breed a Fog dragon?

Comment: For the record, Cactus + Crystal is the *only* combination for a Peridot dragon. No other combos will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Fog Dragon Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Fog_Dragon):

> The Fog Dragon can be bred by using any two dragons, in either order, containing the Water and Air elements at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

Comment: That's good to know but does anyone have any specific combination?

Comment: No specific combo just Air and Water.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that if you want a certain element to be dominate then make sure that dragon is levels above the other one.

Comment: How many levels?